# antd wrapping custom input with auto-complete cause: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, autocomplete, antd

In antd with react, If I've something like the below, everything works fine:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Input>
    <SomeIntermadiateComp/>
...
```

And that some intermediate component looks like this:

```
const SomeIntermadiateComp = React.forwardRef(({ value, onChange }: Props, ref: any) => (
  <Input
    ref={ref}
    value={value}
    onChange={(event) => {
      console.log(event);
      if (onChange) onChange(event.target.value);
    }}
  ...
```

Everything works fine, until, I try to add `AutoComplete`

When I wrap the intermediate component with `AutoComplete`, like:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Input>
    <AutoComplete>
        <SomeIntermadiateComp/>
        ...
```

Then on changing or giving input to intermediate component cause error. Saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at onInputChange (index.js:104)
    at onChange (SingleSelector.js:71)
    at onChange (Input.js:77)
    at onChange (SomeIntermadiateComp.tsx:28)
```

Complete trace is something like:

```
onInputChange
node_modules/rc-select/es/Selector/index.js:104
  103 | var onInputChange = function onInputChange(event) {
> 104 |   var value = event.target.value; // Pasted text should replace back to origin content

onChange
node_modules/rc-select/es/Selector/SingleSelector.js:71
 69 | onChange: function onChange(e) {
  70 |   setInputChanged(true);
> 71 |   onInputChange(e);

onChange
node_modules/rc-select/es/Selector/Input.js:77
  76 | onChange: function onChange(event) {
> 77 |   _onChange(event);

onChange
src/components/SomeIntermadiateComp.tsx:28
  26 |     onChange={(event) => {
  27 |       console.log(`${event.target.value}--`);
> 28 |       if (onChange) onChange(event.target.value);
```

And the funny part is, `` console.log(`${event.target.value}--/`); `` logs the key pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
if (onChange) onChange(event);
```

I guess you should **NOT** write `if (onChange) onChange(event.target.value);`
because inner onChange function needs event argument, not value.